# "Дешевле чем конфискат". Почему нет запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Увидела рекламу в витрине магазина: "Дешевле чем конфискат". Перед "чем" запятая не стояла. Правильно это и, если да, то почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь явное сравнение, поэтому я бы поставила запятую.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, запятая нужна: в обычном тексте. Но реклама - как стихи, здесь возможны отклонения от стандарта! Например, "1 + 1 = 3". Математически неверно, зато наглядно!
Рекламщикам важно воздействие, а не правильность. Нужны крупные буквы, примерно одного размера, запятая здесь просто потеряется.

Answer (score 2):

насчет беспрецедентности - ошибаетесь. В том же репортаже: "в одной только Мексике аналогичных опреций ждут более двадцати человек". Отсюда и поток.

Насчет рекламы. Не все так просто. Намеренная орфографическая ошибка это особая статья, своего рода бренд. А что касается запятых, то все разговоры о них упираются в то, что правила распространяются на грамматически законченную и синтаксичски правильную фразу. В рубленных рекламных слоганах зачастую нет ни того, ни другого. Короче, я не уверен что в нащей рекламе (если это полный текст) "чем конфискат" является классическим сравнительный оборотом, требующим обособления.

Comment: Я слышала  - шесть человек.  Но даже если двадцать... Это их накопилось, пока такие операции не делались. А потом-то... Никак потоком назвать нельзя - это все-таки не аппендицит. Про ошибки в рекламе.  Может, это и бренд. Но  почти нет рекламы без ошибки. Получается. что намеренное искажение нормы становится неотъемлемым свойством рекламы. В том же городе вывеска на магазине "БАльшие  люди". И как мама ребенку объяснит? Да и подсознательно запоминаешь неверное написание. Нет, никак не иогу оправдать намеренное искажение нормы, да и ненамеренное в СМИ тоже.

Comment: >>>>Никак потоком назвать нельзя - это все-таки не аппендицит.    
   
"Вот тут мы вас и поправим!" ©
По мне так так больше двух - уже поток. )))
Как у каких-то там полинезийцев. Из всех числительных - один, два и много.

Про рекламу спорить не буду, хотя это тоже всё очень субъективно. Делать маме больше нечего, как только объяснять, почему дяди правил не знают.

Comment: Иногда намеренное искажение используется как рекламный ход. Например, слышала, что в англоязычных странах используется в этом качестве фонетическое написание слов.  
У нас есть магазин канцтоваров, называется "КанСтанция". Впрочем, здесь большая буква С подчеркивает, что это два слова. Мне эта находка понравилась... 
Другое дело, что в ошибках тоже надо знать меру и иметь вкус. Иначе неожиданным станет написание без ошибки!

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, что даже в рекламе стоит придерживаться нормы. А то так скоро будут и опечатки оправдывать -- мол, в рекламе все можно. Отклонение должно быть осмысленным. В данном случае не вижу смысла не ставить запятую.

Comment: Скажите это им! Не думаю, что им важно наше мнение...

Comment: В рекламе уже давно не придерживаются норм. В нашем крае несколько лет работает торговая сеть магазинов "кАшелка". И закон им не писан. Случай не единичный. Не в тему, просто поделюсь: сегодня в новостях по НТВ сюжет о пересадке обеих рук (страну не помню, мужчине пришили руки убитого боевика). И фраза: мы собираемся поставить такие операции на поток! Представляете - ампутировать обе руки  и пришивать, ампутировать и пришивать!!!!

Comment: Случай, конечно, беспрецедентный... Но вернусь к рекламе и грамотности. Не могу понять рекламщиков, которым правила грамматики неписаны: чем больше ошибок, тем больше они продадут, что ли? Наоборот безграмотность бьет по имиджу, как мне кажется. Во всяком случае в нашем отделе маркетинга и рекламы (Киев) очень тщательно следят, чтобы не было ошибок. И это приятно, с одной стороны... Хотя, к сожалению, мода на грамотность, видимо, куда-то девается...